# External css in plotly dash

Tags: python, html, html5-canvas, plotly, plotly-dash

I'm trying to add external js (from codepen) to my plotly dash app. Using this line:

`app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_scripts=['https://codepen.io/LeonGr/pen/yginI.js'])`

I'm hoping to use this as the application background. Does anyone know if this is possible using plotly dash? If so, where am I going wrong?

I'm unsure of how to add the background element which the js applies to

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure I've understood your question, but I'll take a shot.

You can certainly add external CSS. See [this page](https://dash.plotly.com/external-resources) from the docs and scroll down to "Adding external CSS/Javascript". I see you're already adding the external script, you just need the external stylesheet.

If I've misunderstood, please correct me and I'll try to help more.